# Suppose $g(u) = \int_{2}^{u} \sqrt{1 + t^3} \ dt$. Find the value of $(g^{-1})'(0)$ if it exists.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, inverse-function

I want some verification to see if I am doing this question right. Here is the question, and my attempt:

> Suppose $g(u) = \int_{2}^{u} \sqrt{1 + t^3} \ dt$. Find the value of $(g^{-1})'(0)$ if it exists.

So first I found the derivative of $g(u)$, which was $$g'(u) = \sqrt{1 + u^3}$$

Then I let $v = g'(u)$. The domain of $g'$ is $u\in[-1, \infty)$ and the range of $g'$ is $v\in[0,\infty)$. Now solve for $u$, so
\begin{align*}
v &= \sqrt{1 + u^3} \\
v^2 &= 1 + u^3 \\
u^3 &= v^2 - 1 \\
u &= \sqrt[3]{v^2 - 1}
\end{align*}

So the inverse is $u = \sqrt[3]{v^2 - 1}$, or $(g^{-1})'(v) = \sqrt[3]{v^2 - 1}$. The domain of $(g^{-1})'$ is $v\in[0,\infty)$, and the range for $(g^{-1})'$ is $u\in[-1,\infty)$.

Now find $(g^{-1})'(0)$, so sub $v = 0$.
\begin{align*}
(g^{-1})'(v) &= \sqrt[3]{v^2 - 1} \\
(g^{-1})'(0) &= \sqrt[3]{0^2 - 1} \\
(g^{-1})'(0) &= \sqrt[3]{-1} \\
(g^{-1})'(0) &= -1 \\
\end{align*}

Since the value $-1$ is within the range, this value exists. Therefore, the value of $(g^-1)'(0)$ is $-1$.

This is my attempt, not sure if it is correct...Would like some suggestions or advice, if it is off somewhere.

Comment: You are calculating $(g')^{-1}(0)$ instead of $(g^{-1})'(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing it correctly, you're calculating $(g')^{-1}$ instead of $(g^{-1})'$. To do it correctly, you need the formula
$$ (g^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(x))}$$
Specifically
$$ (g^{-1})'(0) = \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(0))}$$
You properly calculated $$g'(u) = \sqrt{1+u^3} $$
so you just need to find $g^{-1}(0)$ which is such a value $u$ for which $g(u) = 0$, that is
$$ 0 = \int_{2}^u\sqrt{1+t^3}dt$$
even without solving the integral it can be noticed that this equation is satisfied for $u=2$. We have then

$$ (g^{-1})'(0) = \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(0))} = \frac{1}{g'(2)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2^3}} = \frac13$$

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that I was calculating $(g')^{-1}$. As well, I didn't know that they're both completely different. Thank you!